# Can't connect Electrum to a Network so that I can receive my bitcoins

Tags: transactions, linux, electrum

I've looked everywhere for an answer but can't find the right one for my situation. I'm using the linux based tails OS with persistent setup with my electrum wallet. Everything works fine and LBC shows my (test) funds of 0.0011 transferred, yet there's nothing in my wallet even after 45 minutes. Blockchain shows my transactions as complete with 17 confirmations yet still nothing in my electrum wallet. I'm guessing this is because my electrum wallet cannot connect to a network for some reason. I read similar stories but am not sure if it's particular to my problem since I'm using Tails.

Any advice would be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to tell Tails to allow the Electrum client to connect through Tor.

There are very good guides already [here](http://www.deepdotweb.com/jolly-rogers-security-guide-for-beginners/bitcoin-clients-tails-blockchain-electrum/) and [here](https://tails.boum.org/forum/Report_the_electrum_bitcoin_client_in_tails/).

Comment: Thank you so much RommelTJ! You can't imagine the weight you just lifted off my shoulders with those two links. Everything's working fine now except that I have to use the cmd line to go online every time I boot tails. I'm sure the links provided a way around this.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not super familiar with Tails, but could you add that command to your ~/.bash_profile file so that it runs every time you log in? Your system will be less secure, though.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a problem when I installed electrum on ubuntu too. When I use auto-connect it doesn't seem to find a server it can connect too. The thing that worked for me is disabling auto connect and choosing a server manually. Now a lot of servers on the list don't actually work, so one trick I found to quickly find a working server is to scroll thru the list of servers, on the right of the server name is a number (see the picture below). If this number is large (50,000 or so), it seems like the server won't work. If the number is 1000 or less, then it works!

[image]